# Euler equation in comoving coordinate

Tags: fluid-dynamics, cosmology, space-expansion, universe

I have the following cosmology exercise :[image]

I found many hints on internet : [first source](https://www.astro.rug.nl/%7Eweygaert/tim1publication/lss2014/werkcollege.II.27nov2014.pdf), [second source](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/astro/AST4320/h14/beskjeder/combinednotes.pdf)
But I still can't figure it out.

If we is start from

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} +(\vec{v}\cdot \nabla) \vec{v} + \frac{\nabla p}{\rho} + \nabla \phi = 0
\end{equation}

and replace $ \vec{\nabla_x} = a \vec{\nabla}$

we get

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} +(\vec{v}\cdot \frac{1}{a} \vec{\nabla}_x) \vec{v} + \frac{\frac{1}{a} \vec{\nabla}_x p}{\rho} + \frac{1}{a} \vec{\nabla}_x \phi = 0
\end{equation}

then replacing $p=c_s^2 \rho$
we get

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} +(\vec{v}\cdot \frac{1}{a} \vec{\nabla}_x) \vec{v} + \frac{\frac{1}{a} \vec{\nabla}_x c_s^2 \rho}{\rho} + \frac{1}{a} \vec{\nabla}_x \phi = 0  
\end{equation}

which is equivalent to

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} +(\vec{v}\cdot \frac{1}{a} \vec{\nabla}_x) \vec{v} + c_s^2\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{1}{a} \vec{\nabla}_x \rho + \frac{1}{a} \vec{\nabla}_x \phi = 0
\end{equation}

and then replace $\rho = \rho_0 + \delta \rho$ and $p = p_0 + \delta p$ and $\phi = \phi_0 + \delta \phi$

we get

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} +(\vec{v}\cdot \frac{1}{a} \vec{\nabla}_x) \vec{v} + c_s^2\frac{1}{\rho_0 + \delta \rho} \frac{1}{a} \vec{\nabla}_x (\rho_0 + \delta \rho) + \frac{1}{a} \vec{\nabla}_x (\phi_0 + \delta \phi) = 0
\end{equation}

which I think is equal to (because the $\rho_0$ therm are coordinate independent)

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} +(\vec{v}\cdot \frac{1}{a} \vec{\nabla}_x) \vec{v} + c_s^2\frac{1}{\rho_0 +\delta \rho} \frac{1}{a} \vec{\nabla}_x ( \delta \rho) + \frac{1}{a} \vec{\nabla}_x ( \delta \phi) = 0
\end{equation}

but after that I'm stuck... I'm not arriving to formula (2) of my exercise sheet, however it seems quite close idk... Could anyone help me ?

Comment: Use $\vec{v}=H(t)\vec{r}+\vec{v}_p$ and keep only terms linear in perturbation ($\vec{v}_p$, $\delta $ …).

Comment: how does that work to replace $\vec{v} = H(t)\vec{r} + \vec{v_p}$ ? What do you mean keep only terms linera ? does that means that $\delta \rho$ diseapers ?

Comment: *how does that work to replace* … That's just using the definition of $\vec{v}_p$. *What do you mean keep only terms linera*… I mean ignore the terms of second order  perturbation (e.g. assume $\frac{1}{\rho_0 + \delta \rho }\nabla (\delta \rho) \approx  \frac{1}{\rho_0}\nabla (\delta \rho)$, and $(\vec{v}_p \cdot \nabla ) \vec{v}_p\approx 0$ while zeroth order terms should cancel each other (you could check it). And $\delta \rho$ does not disappear from numerator (since it is first order)…

Comment: OK I see thank you. And why is it okay actually to ignore the second order perturbation ?